# "Type Name is not allowed" issue

Tags: c++, struct

So I'm trying to make a header file for math to implement in my game engine. I declared a struct and a function to simply return the struct.

```
typedef struct 
{   
    double x, y;

} Vector2D;

static inline Vector2D vector2D (double x, double y) { return (Vector2D) {x, y}; }
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and it it showing an error.

> Error: type name is not allowed

What can possibly go wrong? Is there any way to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you copy this from C code? The `typedef struct` and `(Vector2D) {x, y}` looking a lot like a compound literal makes me think you might have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What can possibly go wrong?

You are trying cast `{x, y}` to a `Vector2D` here:

```
return (Vector2D) {x, y};
```

> Is there any way to fix it?

Since you are using Visual Studio 2010 I'm assuming that you are using a C++ standard prior to C++11.

Here's how it could be done in C++98 or C++03:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Vector2D {   // note: typedef is not needed for struct/class in C++
    double x, y;
};

static inline Vector2D vector2D(double x, double y) {
    Vector2D rv = {x, y}; 
    return rv;
}

int main() {
    Vector2D rv = vector2D(10, 20);
    std::cout << rv.x << ' ' << rv.y << '\n';
}
```

An alternative could be to add a constructor to `Vector2D`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Vector2D {
    Vector2D(double X, double Y) : x(X), y(Y) {}
    double x, y;
};

static inline Vector2D vector2D(double x, double y) {
    return Vector2D(x, y);
}

int main() {
    Vector2D rv = vector2D(10, 20);
    std::cout << rv.x << ' ' << rv.y << '\n';
}
```

Comment: nope, this isn't about C++11, VS2019 still errors out `error C4576: a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax`. So it appears that `Vector2D {x, y};` is standards conforming and `(Vector2D) {x, y};` is not

Comment: @PeterT I'm sure it does. The correction(s) in my answer works in VS2019 too though. `Vector2D {x, y};` works in C++11 and later. I don't think VS2010 supports that.

Comment: @PeterT Do you have VS2010 so you can test `Vector2D {x, y};`? I don't unfortunately.